# Tests are falling in the headless Chromedriver, Selenium, C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

When running tests in headless chromedriver, the tests fail with errors like "Element not interactable", "element click intercepted" (in the same places). But when I run normal chromedriver the tests pass. I identify elements by XPath.
Why is this happening and how can it be fixed?

Examples of my Chromedriver settings:

Headless:

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArguments("headless");
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Normal:

```
driver = new OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver();
```

Comment: try this one `options.addArguments("window-size=1920,1080");`